# How to get s3 env files in aws sam with github action

Tags: amazon-web-services, environment-variables, github-actions, fastapi, sam

These days I research SAM(Serverless Application Model) to deploy my fastapi sample. However, I can't get the s3 env file. The sam cli command is below.

```
$ sam build --use-container
$ sam deploy
```

The point of error in the code is below.

```
content_object = boto3.resource('s3').Object('config', 'test.json')
```

In the local env, I can get the env file in the s3 bucket, but when I deploy with sam, the error has occurred like this.

```
[ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied
```

How to solve this issue? Have any good sources for getting env files in SAM? I just want to make deploy in github action.

Comment: How are you configuring AWS credentials in the Github Actions workflow? (and using them in the python script with boto3?)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have an issue that loads an env file with SAM (AWS Serverless Application Model) application(FastAPI). However, I can't load the env file in the python script since SAM env is different from Zappa (Zappa can env file with remote_env in the config file). So, I use the copy method in the GitHub action (workflow).